# Period of a particular finite group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a group fitting in the following exact sequence: $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to G \to \mathbb{Z}/q^r \to 0.$ Here $q$ and $p$ are primes (not necessarily distinct). It is easy to check (by the general characterisation in terms of Sylow subgroups, for example) that $G$ has periodic cohomology [edit: unless $p=q$ and the sequence splits, I suppose. Assume the cohomology is cyclic.].

My question is, what **is** the period of the cohomology of this group? To be a bit more specific, what is the minimal length of a periodic resolution of $F$ as an $F[G]$ algebra, where $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$?

I would like the answer to be (a multiple of) $q^{r-l}$ where $q^l$ is the size of the kernel of the action of $\mathbb{Z}/q^r$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p,$ but I have no idea how to prove that (the inspiration of this guess comes from algebraic topology and seems too lengthy to me to explain here fruitfully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p\neq q$ it's precisely $2q^{r-l}$, unless $p=2$, in which case it's $1$.

My initial mental calculation used knowledge of the modular representation theory of groups like this, which seems too lengthy to me to explain fruitfully here (though you might like to check out "Brauer tree algebras"), but I can probably distill a more efficient proof if I think about it.

**Edit:** Here's a construction of a projective resolution of the trivial $FG$-module. I'll assume $p\neq q$ and $p\neq2$ (the other cases are easy).

Let $N=\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $Q=\mathbb{Z}/q^r$, let $g$ be a generator of $Q$, and let $J$ be the augmentation ideal of $FN$. Then there's a filtration
$$0<J^{p-1}<\dots<J^2<J<FN$$
by $FG$-modules. Then $g$ acts on the one-dimensional space $J/J^2$ by multiplication by a primitive $q^{r-l}$th root $\omega$ of $1$.

The short exact sequence
$$0\to J^2\to J\to J/J^2\to 0$$
of $FQ$-modules splits, since $p=\operatorname{char}(F)$ doesn't divide $|Q|$. So we can choose a generator $x$ of $J$ that is an eigenvector for the action of $g$ with eigenvalue $\omega$.

Then $FN=F[x]/(x^p)$.

As an $FN$-module, $F$ has a projective resolution of period $2$
$$\dots\to FN\stackrel{x^{p-1}}{\to}FN\stackrel{x}{\to}FN\to\dots\to FN\stackrel{x^{p-1}}{\to}FN\stackrel{x}{\to}FN\to F\to0.$$

The maps are not $Q$-equivariant. However, we can make them so by tensoring with suitable one-dimensional $FQ$-modules (with trivial $N$-action).

Let $V_i$ (for $i\in\mathbb{Z}/q^{r-l}\mathbb{Z}$) be the one-dimensional $FQ$-module on which $g$ acts by multiplication by $\omega^i$. Then
$$\dots\to FN\otimes V_{-p-1}\stackrel{x}{\to}FN\otimes V_{-p}\stackrel{x^{p-1}}{\to}FN\otimes V_{-1}\stackrel{x}{\to}FN\to F\to0,$$
and this resolution has period $2q^{r-l}$ unless $p=2$ (in which case $x^{p-1}=x$ and $r-l=0$), when it has period $1$.

Comment: Great answer! I'd be happy with any sort of pointer to where to find this, or sketch-proof with words in it I can look up. I'm not sure if your quoting my "explain fruitfully" says something about the quality of my question; I'm happy to explain what I'm doing (I just honestly don't see how it would be helpful).

Comment: @TomBachmann: Sorry, my first answer was slightly wrong: I've corrected it. No, I wasn't getting at you at all, it was just a feeble attempt at humour.

Comment: @TomBachmann: I've edited my answer to add a proof (without any hardcore representation theory).

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean by $FN$? I first thought you meant the linear span of $N$ with $G$ acting by conjugation, but that cannot be right since it has $F$ as a summand. Is it $F[G/Q]$?

Comment: @TomBachmann: Yes, sorry for being confusing. As an $FG$-module what I mean is indeed $F[G/Q]$. As an $FN$-module, this is isomorphic to the regular module $FN$. Since the argument starts by considering projective resolutions over $FN$, I was thinking of it as an $FN$-module with an extra action of $Q$ that extends it to an $FG$-module, but I should have been more explicit about the $G$-action.

Comment: just FYI, contrary to what you say in the first Paragraph, I think the way my question is phrased the answer is always $2q^{r-l}$ for $2 \ne p \ne q$ (I.e. also if $q=2$). Indeed using your resolution to compute $Tor(F, F[x]/x^2)$ one finds $0, X, 0, X\otimes V_{-p}, 0, ...$ (where $X = F[x]/x^2 \otimes V_{-1}$) and so there can be no shorter period than $2q^{r-l}$. (Unless I'm missing something, which is possible at this time of the day.)

Comment: @TomBachmann: Yes, you're quite right. I was getting $p$ and $q$ muddled in my mind at some point. I'll correct the answer. Thanks.